# Redirect stdout in another thread

Tags: scala, redirect, stdout

I am trying to write a test that will redirect the `stdout` of a main method, but it seems that once I call the main, it seems to start on another thread and I cannot capture the output. Here is the code:

This works:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val ps = new PrintStream(baos)
System.setOut(ps)
print("123")
Assert.assertEquals("123", baos.toString)
```

This does not:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val ps = new PrintStream(baos)
System.setOut(ps)
GameRunner.main(_)
Assert.assertEquals("123", baos.toString)
```

....

```
object GameRunner {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        print("123")
```

How can I catch the call to `print` in my test?

*I have also tried `scala.Console.setOut`

EDIT

I do notice that running `GameRunner.main(_)` does not even list anything in the console when I am not redirecting. What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is really `Predef.print` which calls [`Console.print`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Console%24). Even though you call `System.setOut` I don't know if that has an impact on `Console.print`. Try to call `Console.setOut` or try:

```
Console.withOut(ps)(GameRunner.main(null))
```

The other possibility is that by calling GameRunner.main(_) you are not executing anything (as may be it's just returning the function `(args: Array[String]) => GameRunner.main(args)`?. Should be quick to rule that out.

Edit yep:

```
scala> object A { def main(args: Array[String]) { println("1") } }
defined module A   
scala> A.main(null)
1
scala> A.main(_)
res1: Array[String] => Unit = <function1>
```

Comment: As I had edited, `Console.setOut` did not work, however, the `Console.withOut` worked

Comment: Right, on the second account, too. Once I call with main(null) instead of main(_), then it works. I guess I had thought this would act similar since I dont use the args...I will have to figure this out further :) Much appreciated!