# Set a command line argument for Scalatest with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I'm trying to write an integration test for a small command line app I'm writing with Scala and SBT. My app would usually be run from the SBT prompt like so:

```
> run "my arg"
```

The argument "my arg" is accessed in the app with `args(0)`. For an integration test how can I simulate calling `run` with an argument and asserting console output?

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380699/redirect-stdout-in-another-thread

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand that - how do I call `main()` whilst passing in an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app needs to have an `object` with `main` method that takes `Array[String]` as parameter.
It looks like this

```
object Main extends App {
  print("hi, " + args(0))
}
```

or like this

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = print("hi, " + args(0))
}
```

Anyway you definitely have this kind of entry point if you can do `> run "my arg"` in sbt.

It is just an `object` with a method called `main` that you can call wherever you want. Just import it and use:

```
Main.main(Array("my arg"))
```

that would print the text to the console when executed. We need to redirect the console output to some other stream to be able to verify it.

Using answer from [Redirect stdout in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380699/redirect-stdout-in-another-thread) you can come up with something like this:

```
val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val ps = new PrintStream(baos)
Console.withOut(ps)(Main.main(Array("my arg")))
val output = baos.toString
```

And you can do all sort of tests on `output` value

You can then create a helper method to handle this for you

```
def outputFor(args: String*): String = {
  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
  val ps = new PrintStream(baos)
  Console.withOut(ps)(Main.main(args.toArray))
  baos.toString
}
```

And then easly test your app

```
"My app" should "greet me" {
  outputFor("harryg") shouldBe "hi, harryg"
}
```

Just to clarify, the whole solution has nothing to do with `sbt` itself, we directly call the program in a similar way that sbt would do it.